# how to add data into database in django?

Tags: django

I am having trouble about how to solve this problem...Please help me get out of this error...it's also printing the value and database table is already created .following is my code and error says something like Exception Value:

save() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

```
//This is my model.py file
rom django.db import models


class Reg(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20) 

//this is my form.py file
from django import forms


class RegistrationForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField()   


//this is my view.py file
from django.shortcuts import render
    from .forms import RegistrationForm
    from .models import Reg


    def ragistration(request):
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                Reg.name = form.cleaned_data.get('name')
                Reg.save()
                print(Reg.name)
        else:
            form = RegistrationForm()
        return render(request, 'registration/reg.html', {"form": form})



    //I got this error
    Exception Value:    
    save() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is several things you can do here.

1: Use Model form insted of form

```
class RegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Reg
        fields = ['name']
```

2: In your view pay attention to the form.is_valid() part:

```
def ragistration(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            print(form.name)
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()
    return render(request, 'registration/reg.html', {"form": form})
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not creating an instance of class `Reg`. Try this instead

```
reg = Reg()
reg.name = form.cleaned_data.get('name')
reg.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

We have to call save method only on  instance of the model class. We can use model forms to simplify it.

## forms.py

```
from django import  forms
from .models import Reg

class RegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField()
    class Meta:
       model = Reg
       fields = '__all__'
```

## views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .forms import RegistrationForm   

def ragistration(request):
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return HttpResponse("Object Saved") 
        else:
            form = RegistrationForm()
        return render(request, 'registration/reg.html', {"form": form})
```